# .HTACCESS Redirect 301 all files from root directory to sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I am trying to redirect the user accessing my web root directory to a sub directory.

I am trying this:

//301 Redirect Entire Directory

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /1.0/projects/navigator/$1
```

However, it doesnt work, but repeats the path of the sub directory several times:

[my_domain]/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/1.0/projects/navigator/

How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would also like the same as rewrite rule as an alternative to redirect. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the follwoing code at root directory `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1.0/projects/navigator/
# the above line will exclude the same sub directory from the rule below so
# no looping as what happened with you 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /1.0/projects/navigator/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It is not a real redirect even it changes the url in the address bar; resources using relative urls are not working. Maybe that would be expected from a rewrite but should not be the case with a redirect. A real (invisible) rewrite would be the most preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude the path you are redirecting to :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /((?!1.0/projects/navigator).*) /1.0/projects/navigator/$1
```

otherwise you will get a redirect loop error because `/1.0/projects/navigator/`
 also matches the pattern `/(.*)` and redirects the request to same destination multiple times.

Clear your browser's caches before testing this.

Comment: It actually doesnt work as it still loops the two last segments (/projects/navigator/)

Comment: @henrikhansen strange, this code works fine on my apache server.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: I cannot make it work on one.com web host even I clear browser cache in Firefox and Safari...